# Strategies for teaching with facial aphasia (inability to recognize faces aka prosopagnosia, face-blindness)

Tags: teaching, teaching-assistant, disability

I'm a math grad student in my first year, which means that I have not yet taught a class (in my program first years grade or provide one-on-one tutoring for students who struggle in calculus). I have facial aphasia, which means that I am completely unable to recognize people's faces. After a while (upwards a year) I can reliably recognize someone based on how they move, dress, wear their hair and so on. Before that I will just have a vague feeling that I recognize someone, but I can't put a name to them . It happens that I can't recognize people I've lived with for several years, or, on a few memorable occasions, my own family members. This causes some problems on occasion, but nothing I haven't been able to work out. However, up until now the people I've been expected to learn to recognize have been friends, or coworkers I see every day that I can explain my problem with faces to. My question is:

How do I handle teaching when I can't recognize my students and it would take me a year minimum to learn their faces? I know from my own experience that good instructors / TAs learn their students' names and faces and this helps motivate the students to learn, because they notice that their teacher cares about them. How can I compensate for my facial aphasia?

EDIT: Thank you for all the great responses! I feel a lot more confident that I can do well as a TA with all these ideas to work with :)

Comment: In large classes, I don't remember students' faces either. Judging by the way they interact with me, I get the impression that my students *think* I know who they are even when I don't.

Comment: This is a great question, and I hope the answers may also be useful to those of us who are just ordinarily bad at keeping track of faces and names.

Comment: FWIW, students so far never seemed to *expect* me to remember their names just based on classroom interactions. *(but this is based on central Europe, maybe norms in the US are different)*

Comment: @ff524, Johanna seems to be describing the neurological condition [Prosopagnosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopagnosia), which goes ***far*** beyond the everyday inability to remember people's names that all of us have. If I changed glasses / hairstyle / clothing then my wife (who has the condition) would literally not be able to pick me out in a crowd. Or recognise (say) her own mother or father. It's an inability to know (from their face alone) if you have ever met a person before, however close to you or well-known to you that person is.

Comment: I'm terrible with faces, a fact for which I occasionally apologize to students, and in general I don't call on students by name during class. It's a little embarrassing to me, but my students seem to genuinely not mind.

Comment: @AE: Isn't that exactly the situation in large classes described by ff524 and xLeitix, that the lecturer has no idea whether they have ever met any of the students before?

Comment: Are there any characteristics you know you usually use to identify people? They might be a starting point for where to look for ones you could use while teaching. For example, are you good at recognising voices?

Comment: @AE: yes, I understood that. I am questioning the premise that it's necessary to recognize students in order to be a good teacher ("I know from my own experience that good instructors / TAs learn their students' names and faces...")

Comment: @ff524, I see what you're saying. I agree with you that that's the situation for the 'large classes' you mention, assuming they're a couple of hundred people. OP's biggest problem is likely to be in smaller classes or one-to-one tutoring where it would be rude to 'blank' somebody in the lift that you've just spent an hour talking to! ;)

Comment: You could stop believing in the socially constructed myth of absolute facial recognition.  Most actual faces, devoid of surrounding context, do look pretty much alike.  Or I should perhaps say fall into a relative few basic types - think of trying to tell the difference between blonde movie starlets, for instance.  It's sort of like fingerprints.  Yes, every one is unique, but unless you're an expert, you just distinguish loops and whorls.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but: is it possible for you to recognize students by voice instead, if you can't recognize students by face? For example, my family has several cats which look almost identical, but have different facial features; I can distinguish their faces easily, whereas my father is completely incapable of recognizing them by face. However, he can still tell them apart by voice/meow. Likewise, my mother takes phone calls at work often, and can tell who is calling by their voice before they say their name (assuming she has heard their voice before). Could you use voice to help?

Comment: In large classes (auditorium-style seating) that I've attended, I've _never_ expected the lecturer to know me by my appearance. In fact, the only lecturers I _expected_ it from during my undergraduate years were: the professor who also assisted in my degree planning, the department head who I frequently worked very closely with in a 1-on-1 setting, the lecturer who was also my direct supervisor during a summer internship, and the professors of the classes I took with fewer than 10 students. (I would also note that none of the above ever applied to any math course I took!)

Comment: @jamesqf, UCL (London) have done some interesting research on this - my wife has been one of the research subjects. In one of the projects they give her a series of faces, stripped of surrounding context - so not even hairstyles, *just* the face itself - and the difference between her ability and mine, to tell whether the face is that of a famous person (e.g. prime minister, president) is astounding. Of course my recall isn't perfect but I *can* recognise the Queen, for example! :) She just can't.

Comment: @A E: Well, I can't recognize your queen either, except by context :-)  For me, the face is only a minor part of the whole recognition gestalt.  When I think of an absent person, I don't really recall their face, and have a hard time recognizing people from pictures.  Yet I have no great problem recognizing actual people.  (I do much better with dogs & horses, though.)  Bottom line for the OP is to forget about the face recognition problem, and think of the whole person.

Comment: Are you able to distinguish if a person is who they say they are with their ID?  If not I'd be sure to get help from someone who can during exam days lest some sneaky students get their friends to take exams for them.

Answer (score 61):

Unless it is too embarrassing to you, you might actually consider simply telling your students about your facial aphasia at the beginning of the semester.  You can explain that even though you care about them and know who they are as people and students, you won't be able to recognize them by appearance.  A more familiar condition you might make an analogy to is color-blindness.

You might then ask them to identify themselves by something that you *will* be able to recognize them by.  For example:

- If it's a small class, you might make name tags to sit on students' desks in front of them during class.
- In a large class, you might ask students to say their name when they ask a question.

You know your condition best, of course, and what things will work well for you.  You are, of course, admitting a weakness and some of the nastier undergraduates might attempt to use it to play pranks on you or to cheat in some way.  I suspect, though, that at that age in most cases it may be better to play it straight and people will respect you more for doing that than for attempting to hide it.

Comment: Something made me think, "color-coded hats".

Comment: @Raphael In a large lecture class? You'll have to dig deep into the Crayola box for that.

Comment: I know of a person who has face blindness who worked as a barrista -- terrible job for someone with face blindness, because they expect you to know all the regulars.  She scraped by by making a very conscious effort to look for and remember things about the person that she could identify.  For instance, if they always wear the same jewelry or watches, distinctive hairdos, if they came in at a specific time.  In your case though, you can at least have the students also help, if you're comfortable telling them about your face blindness.  Just having them sit in the same seat everyday would help.

Comment: @RogerFan QR-coded hats, then? :)

Comment: "some of the nastier undergraduates might attempt to use it to play pranks on you" - while of course a possibility, in 8 years of studying at university (I dabbled in a couple of things...) I have never seen a student be rude to a lecturer/instructor, let alone actively hassling them. I don't think I'd worry too much about that.

Comment: Thank you for the great ideas! I'll try just explaining it to them and ask for patience and help :)

Comment: I have had a lecturer (who ran his own tutorials), who always insisted on all students putting there names in front of them on a folded page. He didn't have any real difficulty remembering names (not after a few weeks.) but he insisted on it anyway, as the tuitorials were marked on quality of students responses (they were not traditional tuits in that sense.), and he wanted to always make sure the right people were getting the marks.
While your tuits might not be assessed, it does show that asking for name tags is not unheard of in a university enviroment.

Comment: Good answer :)
I am also terrible with names: I don't think I have facial blindness, I am just very distracted..
I turned it into a joke with my students; sometimes I call all of them by the same name (on purpose), sometimes I just try names until I get them... It's a sort of running joke, and it makes them laugh for a bit, and then focus on the question rather than on my.. distraction. If you feel comfortable about it, tell them about the "memorable times" where you couldn't recognize your family members.

Comment: Turning it into a joke also preempts any kind of prank/rudeness from undergrads (which is unlikely anyway, but you never know)

Comment: @G.Bach And I would add one thing. While I know it may not be easy, but it helps if you sort-of accept it as given: When you yourself are willing to make a joke about it, then the nasty students know this isn't gonna help. As an example of similar things: We've had a prof who couldn't walk well, used crutches and was lecturing seated; when someone got noisy during the lecture he said: "Be quiet down there or I strike you with the crutch!" Everybody just laughed.

Comment: Similarly when a black French teacher was explaining the word "(se) rougir" (literally "to redden" with the meaning "to blush"), and he said: "Well, I can't really _me rougis_, you see?"

Comment: @RogerFan Use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors) to pick colors so that they are ``maximally perceptually distinguishable.'' :)

Comment: I'd like to add an addendum to this answer: Make sure you explain *what* facial aphasia is, and that it is a disorder and not just 'forgetfulness'.  I know far, far too many people who would not understand the difference between an actual disorder and just 'forgetfulness', so being quite serious and clear about your explanation is very important.  If your students still do not understand...that's their problem, not yours.

Answer (score 39):

I am absolutely terrible with names and faces. I simply can't remember them. I will forget the name of my next door neighbor of eight years. I have a friend who has facial blindness and I know that there is a difference with what she has. My own version is closer to facial aphasia (recognizes face but cannot recall name) rather than blindness (cannot recognize face), so please take my comments in that context.

I am upfront with my students about this at the beginning of the semester. I tell them I will forget their names repeatedly, but it doesn't mean I don't care about them. They do get confused because one week I will remember their names and then the next week, it'll be an utter blank.  It then becomes a little bit of a running joke in the class but that's ok. I try not to stress too much over it.

Note that there are different strategies for lectures (i.e. big classes where there is minimal expectation that you will have to remember names) and for seminars and discussion groups (where some students will expect you to remember their name). Finally, doctoral students in your own lab will also expect their names to be remembered, but since those are a longer term presence, this can be less of an issue.

Here are some techniques that can be useful for  larger classes and for seminars:

- As some have mentioned, some course management systems  have "photo rosters." I don't find these useful because 1/4 of my students go by nicknames or middlenames that don't show in the CMS. And the photos are very old. And if I could remember someone's name by looking at their face, I wouldn't have this problem to begin with.
- You can ask students to always sit in the same seat each day. For seminars, during roll call, I write down the seating arrangement of the students in my roll call chart. In some schools, students have assigned seating. And so instead of recognizing the face, I can associate the seat with the name -- so I ask Jillian-who-sits-in-the-back-left, not Jillian-who-has-a-face-I-can't-remember.
- I have asked students who look very similar to sit apart. They giggle and think it's a joke, but after a while they realize I really do have a problem and generally comply.
- I ask students to try to wear the same distinctive item. For example, I remembered one student because of the eyeglasses that he wore. The frame stuck better in my mind than his face. When he changed his glasses, 'poof' it was gone.
- I ask students for mnemonics. One student named Steve, I only remembered because he was Japanese-American and made a peace sign, so 'V' -> Steve.  Some students can come up with good mnemonics, others can not.
- You can ask students to have name placards, although most lose them in the first few weeks (and for me, my problem lasts longer than that).
- You can ask them to always say their own name when speaking up. In seminar, you can have them say their own name as well as physically say the name of the student who preceded them in a comment: "This is Charlie, I want to follow up with what Alice just said there...."
- You can make it a running joke so that the students know that they have to help you constantly.  Students are usually surprised when I forget the names of even the most active students in the class, that's when they recognize that it's equal opportunity facial aphasia and that they need to step in to help me.
- You can have your teaching fellow help you. For example, if I talk to a student after class and forget their name, I ask my TF to tell me.
- In seminar, I occasionally nominated a student to go around the table saying all of the names. It helped when I realized that the students only knew half the names. Better than me, but still it showed that we are all fallible. It also encouraged the quieter students to be more vocal if they wanted to be remembered by their peers.
- You can design your classes so that it isn't important for you to have instant recall of their names.
- Ask for things in writing. I have trouble remembering the names of students who come up to me after lecture asking for a variance on their grade or attendance policy. I ask them to send such requests to me by e-mail.
- You can schedule your office hours so students have to sign up with their names in order to see you (i.e., avoid an 'open door' office policy). That way you can greet them by name (and look up their records) before they come.
- For your advisees, you can keep a portfolio on your computer where you record their name, face, year, identifying characteristics (student who always wears a vest, is a smoker (recognize by smell), etc.), and then things about their academic and family life that you'll need the next time you meet them.

In summary, it's not the end of the world and many faculty have difficult with this. Students recognize that they're just one in many. They also recognize the difference between professors who forget who they are because they are apathetic, and faculty who care but genuinely have trouble with this issue. One or two students will consistently raise it in my student evaluations at the end of the semester, but there are enough  more positive comments to overwhelm them.

Again, you'll find many faculty with some version of this. You can ask your learning and teaching center at your school for other tips and techniques.

Note:  You may want to register this as a disability with the disability office. As a student, you may be able to get some support (i.e., an assistant teaching assistant). As a faculty member, it might be helpful to have this in your file so that student complaints about this do not count against you when you are reviewed for promotion and tenure.

Comment: Name placards are a good idea. A colleague of mine deals with the loss issue as follows: he keeps the placards himself between classes. When he  comes in to class each day, he  puts the placards on a table by the door and asks each student to pick up their own, then return it at the end of class. You can make them out of paper or cardboard so they're easily replaced.

Comment: I suppose that helps with keeping attendance as well.

Comment: Your last point, keeping a record of people with identifying features, is a good tip for everyone and in many workplaces as well. It does wonders for customer satisfaction (and avoiding embarrassment) if you're in a client-facing role such as tech support, consultancy or HR.

Answer (score 4):

How about learning from a seating plan? If the class have designated seats, take a note of where each student sits in the class with their corresponding name and then learn that. It may take a while but it will take much less than a year to master.

For me, this idea spawns from waiters in a restaurant, they have to learn the floor plan extremely quickly, and remembering a customers surname when serving 10 tables at once will be very difficult. So having the customers name assigned to a table number makes it much easier to manage.

Good luck in your teaching and I do agree that you should be honest with your students and tell them that you do have this condition. Hopefully they will understand you are trying and support you throughout!

Comment: I've never come across a university setting that has assigned seats (outside of exams, and sometimes not even then).

Comment: Law schools occasionally use assigned seating.

Comment: Even if your institution doesn't normally use assigned seats, you could  certainly adopt that system for your own class. You could even let the students choose their own seating plan.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, students tend to pick a favorite seat and stick to it unless forced to move around. I suspect that if you made a chart of your students favorite 
positions in the first week, it would be pretty accurate for the rest of the term.

Making this chart could also be a good opportunity for you to explain your situation to your students and to ask them to stay in their locations, without making them feel that you are assigning seats as in grade school.

Comment: Thank you David :) I think this could work pretty well in a smaller class or a recitation, which is what I'll be doing for the next few years.

Comment: At least in lecture halls like [this one](http://www.phmi.uni-mainz.de/Dateien/GrosserHoersaal.JPG), I have never encountered such a "favorite seat" behaviour. Many students may have a preferred *half* of the lecture hall (rear or front ...), though even that tends to vary dynamically (arrived late or knows they have to leave early => prefer sitting in the back, or wherever is closest to a door; forgot their glasses => prefer sitting in the front). Also, horizontally, places are mostly determined by the order of arrival (as middle seats are easier to occupy first). ...

Comment: ... And in smaller seminar rooms where tables and chairs can be freely placed, the whole placement of chairs and tables seemed to change every week, anyway, due to other events taking place in those rooms (e.g. job fairs, special presentations, "socializing" events, project meetings with external guests, ...). (All of this is not saying your answer is bad advice, just that it is not very generally applicable across all universities.)

Comment: Agreed regarding large lecture halls. Our small rooms have a default that the seats are supposed to be returned to, and usually are, and that's where I see a favorite seat developing. But sure, I imagine this happens in some situations and not others.